# Low-level Design of a Bike Rental Service

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I'm working on the low-level design of a bike rental service and I was wondering if the solution is good or where it can be improved.

Context & Requirements
I used an exercise I found online which says:

City wants to start a bike rental service based on subscriptions where customers pays an annual fee that will allow them to go to a station, select a bike, undock it, ride and then park it in another station.

It can support two types of bicycles. All stations have a maximum capacity.

The solution should be scalable.

My current design
Image below shows the class design and the endpoints of the API I did.

design of classes, relations and REST API endpoints

[image: Low Level Design bike rental]

Comment: Looks pretty good, except I find the relationship between user and bike a bit odd, and it appears to be missing rentals and rental history.  A user should be able to rent multiple (zero or more) different bikes at the same time, and there should be an order history, rental status (returned or outstanding) a location of where the bike was rented and where (different) returned.

Comment: Robert also makes a good point about the two classes that implement the interface/abstract class.  There's nothing in the diagram that indicates (as to why) that this is useful to do rather than having a simpler Bike class.  It is not clear why you allow setting the bike type (or bike id) -- I'd take those as constructor arguments to class Bike, but given the subclasses, setting the type doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I removed the computer-science and computer-architecture tags because those mean different things.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you could further improve this design on both the objects and the network api.

First, your design currently focuses heavily on the data. It is basically a data model, which is generally considered an anti-pattern in object-orientation. You should instead **focus on behavior**, i.e. what these things should *do*, without exposing their data.

Second, I'm not sure whether the subclassing you introduced actually introduces a different behavior in the subclasses. Does a `MechanicalBike` behave differently *in your app* than an `ElectricBike`? If not there should be no subclassing. Even if yes, **inheritance is really problematic**, you should try to solve it with other tools.

Third, the network **API is backwards**. Consider it this way: If you would create a web app, would you tell me in advance what URIs you will have and what HTTP methods I will have to use on them? Of course not. It is irrelevant. Design the API as you would a web-site. Create the workflows, make it easy to use. Then tell me the landing page and provide links/forms from there.

To do these things right is not easy unfortunately, but this is the direction you could start in.